# Saber la posicion de un arrayList

Tags: c#, arraylist

Tengo este codigo en c# el cual se ingresan datos como:1,3,5,etc y quiero saber la posicion de ese dato pero me sale un error donde dice que la posicion es -1

Ejemplo

se ingresa en un texbox el dato: 3

Despues se desea saber la posicion del dato

en un texbox llamado buscar posicion por dato se ingresa el dato que se desea buscar y se imprime en pantalla la poscion

```
 ArrayList Num = new ArrayList();

private void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n;
        n = int.Parse(txtvalor.Text);
        Num.Add(n);
        txtvalor.Clear();
        txtvalor.Focus();

    }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int pos = Num.IndexOf(textBoxBuscar.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Dato A buscar esta en la poscion: " + pos);

    }
```

Comment: `int pos = Num.IndexOf(textBoxBuscar.Text);` te hace falta convertirlo a `int`. De esta manera: `int pos = Num.IndexOf(int.Parse(textBoxBuscar.Text));`

Comment: Como nota al margen, no debes usar `ArrayList`. Es mejor que uses la versión genérica `List<tipo>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si al ArrayList le estas pasando como valor un entero, entonces porque al buscar su primera coincidencia no le pasas un entero en lugar de una cadena.

```
 ArrayList Num = new ArrayList();

private void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n;
        n = int.Parse(txtvalor.Text);
        Num.Add(n);
        txtvalor.Clear();
        txtvalor.Focus();

    }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int pos = Num.IndexOf(int.Parse(textBoxBuscar.Text));

        if(pos > -1) {
            MessageBox.Show("Dato A buscar esta en la poscion: " + pos);
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("Dato A buscar no se encontro");
        }

    }
```

IndexOf devuelve -1 si no encuentra una coincidencia, de lo contrario retornara indice o posicion.